# Django template for loop and display first X matches

Tags: django, templates

Not sure exactly how to phrase my problem but I essentially want to loop through a list and show the first 4 matches only.

```
{% for reward_type in reward_types %}
    <h2>{{ reward_type.name }}</h2>
    <div class="reward_category">
    {% for category in reward_categories %}
        {% if category.reward_type == reward_type %}
            .
            .
            Show the first 4 matches
            .
            .
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You might find slice useful, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice . I would probably move the logic part elsewhere and have that return a list I could apply that slice filter on.

Comment: yeah i think i should handle this in my view function

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Use your view function to prepare your list before passing it to the template.

Django template isn't intended for complex matching like this.

Exactly as discussed ;-)

Comment: -1, "Django template is not indended blah blah" is getting old. A template language should have basic data manipulation operations, including slicing, filtering and sorting. (In fact it does, see Rohan's answer.)

Answer (score 27):

You could have used [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice) if there isn't `{% if category.reward_type == reward_type %}`.

i.e. if you have `category_matching_rewards` which is list having `category.reward_type == reward_type` then in template it can be done as

```
{%for category in category_matching_rewards|slice:"4" %}
       Show catgory
       ....
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Sweet!  Why isn't this the accepted answer over, "You can't get there from here"?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `forloop.counter`, The `for` loop sets a number of variables available within the loop:

`forloop.counter`   The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)

`forloop.counter0`  The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)

`forloop.revcounter`    The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1-indexed)

`forloop.revcounter0`   The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0-indexed)

`forloop.first`     **True** if this is the first time through the loop

`forloop.last`  **True** if this is the last time through the loop

`forloop.parentloop`    For nested loops, this is the loop *above* the current one

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for)