# Breaking or stopping a forloop.counter in django

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I applied a `forloop.counter` to label each object numerically in a `for` loop But I want it to number only the *first fifty(50)* objects and ignore the rest. Here is my code

```
{% load thumbnail %}

{% for image in most_viewed %}

<div class="image">
<a href="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}">
{% thumbnail image.image "200x200" crop="10%" as im %}
<span class="forloop">**{{ forloop.counter }}**</span>
<a href="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}"> <img src="{{ im.url }}">  </a> 

{% endthumbnail %}

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Basically, objects 51 and above should be without numbers

Comment: Why not just `{% if forloop.counter < 50 %}`?

Comment: does slice do what you want? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12474131/4872140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **slice** to rewrite the *for loop* as

```
{% for image in most_viewed|slice:":50" %}
```

It will do the iteration for first 50 image in *most_viewed*.

Edit - Just saw your edit. You can try using the conditional statement **forloop.counter <= 50**

```
{% for image in most_viewed %}

  <div class="image">
    ...
    {% if forloop.counter <= 50 %}
      <span class="forloop">**{{ forloop.counter }}**</span>
    {% endif %}
    ...
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: your solution works but i encountered an issue. I use ajax pagination so when I scroll down and load more content, the counter restarts from 1 up to 50 again and the circle repeats itself again and again. Let me know if I need to elaborate any further.